# Как прочитать std::string до определенного символа без лишнего копирования? С++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть такая строка:

```
std::string str {"Hahaha/adadsdsd/asdadsd"};
```

Мне нужно разбить эту строку на подстроки, разделенные символами слэша. И я хочу узнать, есть ли встроенные алгоритмы для таких случаев?
Я знаю про `getline`, но он требует в качестве первого аргумента `std::stringstream`, а его создание требует лишнего копирования всей строки:

```
std::stringstream stream{str}; // тут копирование
```

Comment: Начиная с С++20 строку можно перемещать, а не копировать: `std::stringstream stream{std::move(str)};`.

Comment: Мне кажется проще написать свою функцию.

Comment: Может, плюнуть на `string` и воспользоваться `strtok`?

Comment: А что вы хотите на выходе получить?

Comment: std::string_view(&str[0], str.find('/')) например

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ваш способ хорош, то что надо, но, боюсь, не совсем. find() возвращает позицию первого элемента. "Распарсить" строку не получится

Comment: @HolyBlackCat разумеется, но если существует алгоритм из std, то предпочтительнее использовать его. Разве не так?) Я был уверен, что нечто такое существует, но ошибся

Comment: Функция-то есть, называется [`std::views::split`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view)... Только вот пример с ней у меня завелся только в MSVC, а в GCC и Clang - нет. :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а в чем проблемы этой функции? Новый стандарт не все компиляторы поддерживают?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @ComeInRage  это всего лишь подсказка, дальше  в цикле получать все остальные  string_view начиная от позиции полученной  функцией членом find().